# How to describe a shop selling handmade designer goods in one or two words?

Tags: single-word-requests

I need to find a word which will mean the following: a shop which sells handmade designer goods like knitwear (made by both crochet and knitting needles), embroidery, beadworks, clothes.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Could not find one word. If it's handmade craft, you might call it a 'handicraft shop'/crafts shop'. If it's oriented more towards personalized clothing then 'boutique' might also be used.

Comment: Naming things is in general off-topic here. I don't think there's one word which covers needlework,  beadwork, and clothing.

Comment: custom-made; one-off; what's wrong with handmade goods?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the term  "***Artisanal [Needlework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needlework) Boutique***" is what you are looking for, all of the examples listed being needlework.

"**Fancywork Boutique**" would be another term for it, but needlework is the catchall term for the products listed.

> **[needlework](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/needlework)**- Things made by embroidery, knitting, or needlepoint.
>
> **[fancywork](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/fancywork)**- Ornamental needlework, crochet, or knitting, as opposed to
> plain or purely functional stitches.
>
> **[boutique](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/boutique)**- A small store selling fashionable clothes or accessories. A business or establishment that is small and
> sophisticated or fashionable.